# Change Button when Audio is finished Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, avaudioplayer

i am making app with Xcode using Swift and i have mp3 file in my app and i have added Play and Pause Button in it but my problem is that when i click on Play button Pause button shows but when mp3 file finished playing there is still pause button display and i want it to change to Play button again automatically when audio finished .
 this is my code

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if player.isPlaying {

        player.stop()
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),for: .normal)
    } else {
        player.play()
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),for: .normal)
    }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement **AVAudioPlayerDelegate** in class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
   ...
```

and use this function inside class:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: @ChandNinder also set `player.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: i just forgot to add player.delegate = self before player.play() btw thanks for your help ,, it works